# Calculating X results from X feature classes in successive manner via ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am trying to calculate Cumulative Focal Mobility Network in ArcMap 10.8.1 and I am new to ModelBuilder. Basically, this procedure requires creating a cost surface (via Cost distance from Slope model) from which is the Flow direction calculated, which itself serves as basis for calculation of Flow accumulation, which is converted to polylines, which are finally analysed via Density. Result should be a map of optimal routes (network) in the region…

The trick is, that this procedure should be completed for grid of equally spaced points, in my case 120. That is rather tedious manually, so I tried ModelBuilder via Iterate Feature Classes for the input points. Each time it only crashes (see fig. 1). I do not know how to enter via tools available the simple query: “Calculate 120 models from 120 points stored in a folder in successive manner and save them in specified folder”.

[image]

I can’t find the way to force ModelBuilder to calculate the initial part, after which there will be two more rounds of the same: 120 rasters generated from 120 source data in successive manner.

Comment: So do you have 120 shapefiles in your folder each with a single point? Or do you have 1 shapefile with 120 points in it, if so you need to be using the [iterate feature selection](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Hornbydd for your suggestion! Yes, I have 120 points in one file. I was using "Iterate feature classes" instead of "Iterate feature selection". Now everything works as I wanted.